# Powershell accessing embedded properties

Tags: powershell

I am working in Powershell and the result of some queries return a collection member like this (note that this is shortened from the actual output):

```
SmsProviderObjectPath : SMS_SCI_SysResUse.FileType=2,ItemName="[\"Display=\\\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\\\"]MSWNET:[\"SMS_SITE=MBC\"]\\\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\\,SMS Distribution Point",ItemType="System 
                        Resource Usage",SiteCode="MBC"
FileType              : 2
ItemName              : ["Display=\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=MBC"]\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\,SMS Distribution Point
ItemType              : System Resource Usage
NALPath               : ["Display=\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=MBC"]\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\
NALType               : Windows NT Server
NetworkOSPath         : \\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG
PropLists             : {BindExcept, Protected Boundary, SourceDistributionPoints, SourceDPRanks...}
Props                 : {BITS download, Server Remote Name, PreStagingAllowed, SslState...}
RoleCount             : 2
RoleName              : SMS Distribution Point
SiteCode              : MBC
SslState              : 0
Type                  : 8
PSComputerName        : prim-serv.MYDOMAIN.org
PSShowComputerName    : False
ManagedObject         : \\prim-serv\root\sms\site_MBC:SMS_SCI_SysResUse.FileType=2,ItemName="[\"Display=\\\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\\\"]MSWNET:[\"SMS_SITE=MBC\"]\\\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\\,SMS 
                        Distribution Point",ItemType="System Resource Usage",SiteCode="MBC"
OverridingObjectClass : SMS_SCI_SysResUse
RegMultiStringLists   : {}
SecurityVerbs         : -1
ObjectClass           : SMS_SCI_SysResUse
Properties            : 
                        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = "IsPXE";
                            Value = 0;
                            Value1 = "";
                            Value2 = "";
                        }, 
                        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = "IsActive";
                            Value = 0;
                            Value1 = "";
                            Value2 = "";
                        }, 
                        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = "IsPullDP";
                            Value = 0;
                            Value1 = "";
                            Value2 = "";
                        }, 
                        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = "IsMulticast";
                            Value = 0;
                            Value1 = "";
                            Value2 = "";
                        }, 
                        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
                        {
                            PropertyName = "LastIISConfigCheckTime";
                            Value = 1490896883;
                            Value1 = "";
                            Value2 = "";
                        }};
                            RoleCount = 2;
                            RoleName = "SMS Distribution Point";
                            SiteCode = "MBC";
                            SslState = 0;
                            Type = 8;
                        };

PropertyNames         : {FileType, ItemName, ItemType, NALPath...}
MethodNames           : 
MethodList            : {}
PropertyList          : {[FileType, 2], [ItemName, ["Display=\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=MBC"]\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\,SMS Distribution Point], [ItemType, System Resource Usage], 
                        [NALPath, ["Display=\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=MBC"]\\SERVER1.MYDOMAIN.ORG\]...}
UniqueIdentifier      : 16242167-3aac-4b79-ad5b-2c8030922ba5
ParentResultObject    : 
GlobalDisplayString   : 
AutoCommit            : False
AutoRefresh           : False
UserDataObject        : 
ConnectionManager     : Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.PowerShell.Provider.CmdletWqlConnectionManager
TraceProperties       : True
NamedValueDictionary  : {[AllProviderLocations, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]], [ProviderLocation, 
                        \\prim-serv\ROOT\sms:SMS_ProviderLocation.Machine="prim-serv.MYDOMAIN.org",SiteCode="MBC"], [ProviderMachineName, prim-serv.MYDOMAIN.org], [Connection, 
                        \\prim-serv.MYDOMAIN.org\root\sms\site_MBC]...}
AsyncOperationData    : 
RetainObjectLock      : False
```

I can access many of the items listed, such as "NetworkOSPath" and "RoleName" with code like this:

$myDP = $DP.NetworkOSPath

I am at a loss how to reference items listed in the Properties area such as:

IsPXE, IsPullDP and the values associated with them.

I can get a listing of them using the command:  $dp.EmbeddedProperties | format-list *

This produces a listing of Keys and Values:

```
Key   : AllowInternetClients
Value : 
        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
        {
            PropertyName = "AllowInternetClients";
            Value = 0;
            Value1 = "";
            Value2 = "";
        };


Key   : BITS download
Value : 
        instance of SMS_EmbeddedProperty
        {
            PropertyName = "BITS download";
            Value = 1;
            Value1 = "";
            Value2 = "";
        };
```

In an effort to just list a specific key, I've tried the following without success:

```
foreach ($DP in $DPList) {$DP.EmbeddedProperties | select-object -expandproperty IsPXE }

foreach ($DP in $DPList) {$DP.EmbeddedProperties | Select-Object where Name = "IsPXE"}

foreach ($DP in $DPList) {$DP.EmbeddedProperties | Select-Object IsPXE}
```

Is there a way to reference the key and their associated values so that I can assign them to variables inside of my script?

Comment: It looks like both `$DP` and `$DP.Properties` are objects that implement the [`IResultObject` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.configurationmanagement.managementprovider.iresultobject.aspx), and the latter contains [`SMS_EmbeddedProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc145060.aspx) instances. Can you run `$DP.Properties.GetType()` to see what the runtime type of that property is? Have you tried `$DP.Properties['IsPXE']` or `$DP.Properties | ? PropertyName -eq 'IsPXE'`?  Also, in your last snippet how come you are using `EmbeddedProperties` instead of `Properties`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were so close with `$dp.EmbeddedProperties`. Just keep dotting and you'll get there. Once you get the value you are looking for, you can add it to an object. Here's an example:

```
$dp = Get-CMDistributionPoint
$NewObj = @()
ForEach ($d in $dp)
{
    $ServerName = $d.NetworkOSPath
    $IsPXE = $d.embeddedproperties.IsPXE.Value
    $NewObj += [pscustomObject]@{ ServerName = $ServerName; IsPXE = $IsPXE }
}
$NewObj | Out-GridView
```

BE CAREFUL - Once you dot-note passed EmbeddedProperties, you enter the eerie world of Case-Sensitivity! If you don't have it correct, you get NOTHING! I'm not sure why. perhaps it has something to do with the .NET's System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary class and Case-Sensitive String Keys?
IE

```
$d.embeddedproperties.IsPXE.Value ##This works.
$d.embeddedproperties.IsPXe.Value ##This does not work.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the properties section is just text. Was the contents of ($dp.EmbeddedProperties | format-list *) wrapped in quotes when it was added to $dp? Make previous sections of your script are not dumping text into your object. Keep objects as objects as much as possible.

I had issues like this when working with outputs like this

```
get-adgroupmember -identity $name | select stuff
```

until I switched to a better method

```
(get-adgroupmember -identity $name).stuff
```